# php redirect from certain referral domain

Tags: php

On stackereurope.com are European contact details.

Now there is a new domain for the UK called stackereurope-uk.com.

It should display the same website only with different contact details.

I am thinking about this solution:
On the UK domain I put an iframe that opens the original website.

On the original website I put (on the contact page)
If the referral is stackereurope-uk.com redirect to stackereurope-uk.com/contact/

The code to redirect should be something like this?

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

if (($domain == "stackeurope.com" ||
    $domain == "stackereurope-uk.com") && !$_GET['redirected'])  { 
    header("location: http://stackereurope-uk.com/contact/index.php"); 
}
?>
```

I tried this code but that doesn't work.

What is the easiest way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: ***What*** doesn't work?

Comment: do you get any errors?? in which file do you save your code? in contact/index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead. If I remember correctly, if the server runs on a port other than 80 (as might be common on a development/intranet machine) then `HTTP_HOST` contains the port, while `SERVER_NAME` does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to redirect based on the referring domain, you might want to try using [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) on [HTTP_REFERER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), and then working with the host return value.

For example:

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo $uri['host'];
```